# eclipse plugin to validate software architecture

Tags: java, plugins, architecture

May I know is there a plugin that can validate software architecture? i.e. whether the code conforms to the layered architecture for example.

Answer (score 6):

Structure101 plugin can do this, in combination with the standalone program.
http://structure101.com/products/structure101/plugins/

Structure101 is a commercial product (http://structure101.com/products/purchase.php), but it is really good and you can define your own rules that the developers should follow.

Comment: +1, but how to generate any diagram at Eclipse. I have installed plugin.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to create the diagrams in the structure101 application and then publish them a s101 repo, which can be used by the plugin. http://structure101.com/products/structure101/plugins/

Comment: There's a guide, http://structure101.com/products/structure101/walkthrough/, to walk you through the setup.

Comment: @pth-Structure101, I was looking to this kind of document, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin architecture is becoming very popular for its extensibility and thus flexibility.
Eclipse is definitely plugin based

You can find many options in the eclipse Marketplace.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/software%2520architecture

I have seen some good Software Architecture plugins there like:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rational-software-architect#.UTbyCKvFWwk

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/523210#.UTbyR6vFWwk

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/metamodelagent-ibm-rational-software-architect#.UTb0yavFWwk

Comment: Build software architecture that supports change with a common platform that facilitates easy roundtrip engineering and synchronization of models and code.
Accelerate implementation and facilitate maintenance of a service-oriented architecture (SOA) solution, such as a web service, with tools and process guidance.
Use UML to ensure the numerous stakeholders within your software development projects are continuously communicating, and use defined specifications to jumpstart development.